# Is Web.Config culture-invariant?

Tags: asp.net, localization, globalization

As a developer of an HttpModule that is used in over 150 countries, I want to make sure I'm doing the right thing by making all web.config data culture-invariant. This means any date/time values, floating-point, or integers specified in Web.config should be parsed with the invariant culture (generic english).

Is this the correct convention to follow? Extensive googling didn't turn up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you use the invariant culture for all configuration settings in Web.config, because that is the convention followed by ASP.NET. Your users will probably find it confusing to have to specify invariant data in certain places and localized data in other places.

(ASP.NET relies on the functionality in `System.Configuration` to parse configuration data. The internal `ConfigurationProperty.ConvertFromString` method calls `TypeConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString` to convert a string to a typed value. You too can use `System.Configuration`; see the [MSDN Library documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178688.aspx).)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that there even is a convention for this. Come to think of it I'm not sure what I would expect. I would probably be surprised if the module didn't behave as expected because a setting was parsed in an unexpected culture.

But let's say for the sake of argument you want to do follow a different convention (not invariant by default). I think it would be most logical to read the [`<globalization>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) settings and use the `culture` setting (not the `uiCulture` because that is for loading resources).

This way it is configurable for your customers. Of course you need to take care to use an `IFormatProvider` based on the culture setting to parse the settings:

```
string setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["size"];
IFormatProvider format = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(configSection.Culture).NumberFormat;
float size = float.Parse(setting, format);
```

I'd say it would be good to cache the configuration setting in `HttpContext.Application` the first time it's read. If web.config changes the app domain will be reloaded anyway.

A possible downside is that when you want to document your library you will have to educate users that they can't just copy-paste configuration values since their environment may have a different culture setting and thus they may encounter errors that could be hard to understand.

PS. Looking at the [configuration documentation](http://imageresizing.net/docs/configuration-all) for your module, I noticed the `<cleanupStrategy>` element. That looks unusual to me. I would expect to specify its values in seconds or some other integer value, like `<sessionState timeout="number of minutes">`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Another concern I'm having is that it prevents web.config files from being portable between machines. It's not uncommon for the developer and the server to be running different culture settings (Ex. EC2 defaults to english).